# Are there options like visual studio's "Go to definition" in visual web developer?

Tags: css, visual-web-developer, visual-web-developer-2010

In visual studio I can right-click on most things (methods, class instances, local variables...) and I get options for "Go to definition" and "Find all references".

Is there anything like that in visual web developer? In particular, can I somehow get every place where a specific style in a CSS file is used (-I see the style in a CSS page, and want to know if and where is it being used)?

(I'm referring to a web application project. Does it matter?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being I'm assuming they don't exist. If they do – please feel free to correct me.

(I'm accepting my answer, as opposed to the other, because it probably *is* possible. The question is only if it has been done in VWD.)

Answer (score 0):

Nope. That's not available yet.
I don't see how that is possible on css classes since those features rely on reflection.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2012 if you highlight the css class and hit f12 it should take you to style definition.